# How to capture all user activities [ not any application specific] on a windows machine?

Tags: python, .net, windows

I am trying to identify a solution to capture all the user activities on a windows machine. These activities can not be any application specific. For e.g. user can launch multiple windows / web based applications, change background wallpaper, increase speaker volume etc, so basically every operation that s/he does on the machine.

Is there any way to capture it using any .NET / Python / Any other language API / Tool?

Comment: Write a Windows driver that hooks on mouse and keyboard events

Comment: Try to record each events individually in the first place. Catching keystrokes is pretty easy for exemple.

Comment: The fact that you want to records such things seems pretty stange by the way.

Comment: @Amperclock Lol. Looks like a spyware to me too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand a windows driver can be built that hooks mouse / keyboard, but I was just wondering if there is any readily available APIs which does the same.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a driver. There are global mouse and keyboard hooks available in Win32 API ([SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) function).

This is [a Python example](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/hook_and_listen.py) watching for specific keys and mouse clicks for 5 seconds.

Also in UIAutomation technology Automation Event handlers can be registered for structure/property changes (globally). We're trying to use these handlers for "record-replay" script generator for pywinauto. It's still a prototype though.